# SQL with PHP variables

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to update db record using the code below. Even if the redirection is done, the record isn't being updated as it should be. any tips please?

```html
<?php
session_start();
?>
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "Mydatabase";
$id = $_GET["session_id()"];


// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "UPDATE leads SET first_name='hola' WHERE id = '$id'";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    header( "thank-you.php" ); die;
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: `var_dump($_GET["session_id()"])`?

Comment: Having the session ID as a key on the query-string seems like a bit of a strange situation to be in, just as an observation. Is that what you're actually trying to do?

Comment: is it `$_GET["session_id()"]` or `$_GET["session_id"]` ? Try `var_dump($id)`

Comment: Watch out with passing session_id's in the query string. This makes it much more easier for sessions to get hijacked by others!

Comment: thanks for the tips, I used id from db instead and it's working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one causes the problem.

```
$id = $_GET["session_id()"];
```

`session_id()` itself is a PHP function. No need for quoting. Just remove the quotes and it should be fine.

```
$id = $_GET[session_id()];
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, I used id from db, I think it's better and it's working